# перебор значений условного форматирования

Tags: excel, vba

В файле пользователями копируются строки, столбцы, ячейки, диапазоны, в результате чего количество задублированных правил условного форматирования переваливает за тысячу (при начальных 40). Я хочу проверять есть ли на листе дублированные правила условного форматирования и удалять их с помощью VBA, но не пойму каким образом получить доступ (и можно ли это сделать) к перечню правил. Доступ к стилям ячейки можно получить через
`Dim fc As FormatCondition test = fc.Type (или) test = fc.Interior.Color`
а целиком "правило" можно просмотреть?
Есть конечно вариант перебора всех правил УФ в диапазоне `For Each fc In range.FormatConditions` и сравнение всех свойств правил между собой. Если они полностью совпадают - удалять одно из правил, но мне видится это очень ресурсозатратным как в плане разработки (нужно понять какие свойства объекта fc нужно сравнивать), так и в плане отработки (тысяча правил на листе)

Comment: Не стоит усложнять себе жизнь. Вы знаете, какой набор правил был применён к таблице до того, как пользователи там намусорили? Просто очистите все правила без проверки на дубли и создайте первоначальные с нуля

Comment: Это был запасной план. Дело в том что файл предоставляет смежное подразделение в большой компании, и я не уверен что мое начальство одобрит дергать смежников с просьбой предоставлять обновленный перечень правил каждый раз (он периодически меняется). Думал есть красивый стандартный метод для перебора правил и их значений.

Comment: Это тупиковый подход. Например, для двух диапазонов применено одинаковое правило. Как понять - это дублированное правило или так задумано (не указали  для одного правила два диапазона, но создали два одинаковых правила для разных диапазонов)?

Comment: Можно пробегать по столбцам и искать дублированные правила в рамках столбца. Что правда еще больше увеличит время отработки макроса. Прежде чем думать об этих вопросах, я хотел узнать есть ли метод "получить" правило как набор стилей, чтобы сравнивать правила в диапазоне между собой. Если нет - остается банальный перебор, тогда я и буду думать насколько это целесообразно.